# pdflatex not working with ACM class files on 17.10

Tags: 17.10, texlive

Since upgrading to 17.10, I get the following error building a LaTeX document with `pdflatex`:

```
pdflatex (file lbtn_c7kyj5.enc): cannot open encoding file for reading
```

From this [Solus discussion](https://dev.solus-project.com/T4164), I gather the problem is related to the Libertine font encodings and changes to TeX Live. There is also some ArchLinux discussion [here](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/53936).

To reproduce, download the latest ACM class file from http://www.sigplan.org/sites/default/files/acmart/current/acmart.cls and run `pdflatex` on the following file:

```
\documentclass{acmart}

\begin{document}
Nothing to see here $:$
\end{document}
```

The math-mode colon (or similar) is required to trigger the error.

Has anyone else run into this issue, and are there any solutions I could try? (It sounds like downgrading TeX Live may fix it, but I don't feel confident about attempting that.)

Answer (score 1):

Downgrading to `texlive2016-20160523` fixes this. Download from ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2016/.